# Facing issue in nextFocusRight for edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I have a custom editext in android with GothicRegular font like this :

```
public class EditText_GothicRegular extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    public EditText_GothicRegular(Context context) {
        super(context);
        disableCopyPaste();

    }


    public EditText_GothicRegular(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        disableCopyPaste();
    }

    public EditText_GothicRegular(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        disableCopyPaste();

    }

    private void disableCopyPaste() {

        setTypeface(Fonts.gothic_regular);
    }

}
```

And i have implemented in the design like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"

        >

        <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.Gothic_Bold
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/registertitle_txt"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text20" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.EditText_GothicRegular
                    android:id="@+id/fullname"
                    style="@style/Edittext"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name_icon"
                    android:hint="@string/fullname_txt"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/mobileno"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:text=""
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.EditText_GothicRegular
                    android:id="@+id/mobileno"
                    style="@style/Edittext"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mobile_icon"
                    android:hint="@string/mobileno_txt"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|number"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.EditText_GothicRegular
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    style="@style/Edittext"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
                    android:hint="@string/password_txt"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:text=""
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.EditText_GothicRegular
                        android:id="@+id/selectstate"
                        style="@style/Edittext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location_icon"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/drop_down_arrow"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="@string/selectstate_txt"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
                        android:text=""
                        android:maxLines="1"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/statespinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding5"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/accept_tnc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding5"
                        android:id="@+id/accept_tnc_img"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/remember_radio_inactive"

                        />

                    <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.Gothic_Bold
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/iagree"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"

                        />

                    <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.Gothic_Regular
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding5"
                        android:text="@string/accepttnc"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.Gothic_Bold
                    android:id="@+id/register_button"
                    style="@style/Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:text="@string/register_txt" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i try to hit the next button on the keyboard from fullname it goes to password instead ok mobile number even after giving `nextfocusright`. The issue is resolved if i remove the `textsize` given in  `style="@style/Edittext"` as shown below :

```
<style name="Edittext">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text16</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/clrfe</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: add `parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Not solving the issue